# Setting up CodePipeline with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I am new to Terraform and building a CI setup. When I want to create a CodePipeline that is going to be connected to a GitHub repo, do I run specific commands inside my Terraform codebase that will reach out to AWS and create the CodePipeline config/instance for me? Or would I set this CodePipeline up manually inside AWS console and hook it up to Terraform after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

> do I run specific commands inside my Terraform codebase that will reach out to AWS and create the CodePipeline config/instance for me?

Yes, you use [aws_codepipeline](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codepipeline) which will create **new pipeline** in AWS.

> Or would I set this CodePipeline up manually inside AWS console and hook it up to Terraform after the fact?

You can also [import existing](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) resources to terraform.

Answer (score 0):

I see you submitted this eight months ago, so I am pretty sure you have your answer, but for those searching that comes across this question, here are my thoughts on it.

As most of you have researched, terraform is infrastructure as code (IaC). As IaC it needs to be executed somewhere.  This means that you either execute locally or inside a pipeline.  A pipeline consists of docker containers that emulate a local environment and run commands for you to deploy your code.  There is more to that, but the premise of understanding how terraform runs remains the same.

So to the magic question, Terraform is Code, and if you intend to use a pipeline, Jenkins, AWS, GitLab, and more, then you need a code repository to put all your code into.  In this case, a code repository where you can store your terraform code so a pipeline can consume it when deploying your code.  There are other reasons why you should use a code repository, but your question is directed to terraform and its usage with the pipeline.

Now the magnificent argument, the chicken or the egg, when to create your pipeline and how to do it.   To your original question, you could do both.  You could store all your terraform code in a repository (i recommend), clone it down, and locally run terraform to create your pipeline.  This would be ideal for you to save time and leverage automation.  Newbies, you will have to research terraform state files which is an element you need to backup in some form or shape once the pipeline is deployed for you.

If you are not so comfortable with Terraform, the GUI in AWS is also fine, and you can configure it easily to hook your pipeline into Github to run jobs.

You must set up Terraform and AWS locally on your machine or within the pipeline to deploy your code in both scenarios.  This article is pretty good and will give you the basic understanding of [setting up terraform](https://blog.gruntwork.io/an-introduction-to-terraform-f17df9c6d180)

Don't forget to configure AWS on your local machine.  For you Newbies using pipeline, you can leverage some of the pipeline [links to get you started](https://github.com/cwnit/toolkits/tree/master/collections/terraform). Remember one thing, within AWS Codepipeine; you have to use IAM roles and not access keys.  That will make more sense once you have gone through the first link.  Please also go to youtube and search Terraform for beginners in AWS.  Various videos can provide a lot more substance to help you get started.